# How to avoid modified closures with ThreadStart

Tags: c#, multithreading, lambda, closures, resharper

I'm getting an "Access to modified closure" error in Resharper. Is there a way to pass the task as a parameter to the lambda instead of relying upon a closure?

```
        while (!Quitting && TaskQueue.Any())
        {
            foreach (var task in TaskQueue.ToArray())
            {
                if (Quitting || task.Code == TaskCode.Quit)
                {
                    Quitting = true;
                    return;
                }
                if (!task.Runnable)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                var thread = new Thread(() =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        task.Callback();
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        if (task.Error != null)
                        {
                            task.Error(e);
                        }
                    }
                });
                thread.Start();

            }

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [`Thread.Start(object state)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x4c42hc.aspx) method:

```
while (!Quitting && TaskQueue.Any())
{
    foreach (var task in TaskQueue.ToArray())
    {
        if (Quitting || task.Code == TaskCode.Quit)
        {
            Quitting = true;
            return;
        }
        if (!task.Runnable)
        {
            continue;
        }

        var thread = new Thread(state =>
        {
            var taskState = (Task)state;
            try
            {
                taskState.Callback();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                if (taskState.Error != null)
                {
                    taskState.Error(e);
                }
            }
        });

        thread.Start(task);
    }
}
```

which would have been equivalent to using a separate function:

```
private void Process(object state)
{
    var task = (Task)state;
    try
    {
        task.Callback();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        if (task.Error != null)
        {
            task.Error(e);
        }
    }
}
```

which you would have passed like that:

```
while (!Quitting && TaskQueue.Any())
{
    foreach (var task in TaskQueue.ToArray())
    {
        if (Quitting || task.Code == TaskCode.Quit)
        {
            Quitting = true;
            return;
        }
        if (!task.Runnable)
        {
            continue;
        }

        new Thread(this.Process).Start(task);
    }
}
```